# Should I rely on nextjs 'pages/_error.js' for error handling or use React ErrorBoundary?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using nextjs for quite a while now. I relied on _error.js page provided by nextjs when there is any error. In their [doc here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/error-handling), it is specified to use errorboundary. Should I continue relying or next.js _error.js page or add errorboundary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_error.js` page is just a customization when the application throws a 500 error.

> 500 errors are handled both client-side and server-side by the Error component. If you wish to override it, define the file pages/_error.js and add the following code:

Error Boundaries are a React JS concept - Think of them as fallback components that can receive the error and display it or you can handle it yourself - It's considered as a best practice

They cover completely different areas of the stack.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the `_error` page will only handle errors that happen on the server. To handle client-side errors you'll want to use Error Boundaries.